# How to stop flex to auto adjusting, currently based on text length its auto adjusting. I want the entire table to be same size despite any text length

Tags: css

How to get this aligned as i was not able to align

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span>Total Items: @Model.Count </span>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
            <span class="text-black-50">Sort by:</span>
            <div class="price ml-2">
                <span class="mr-1">price</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick solution, assign the elements a specific  percent width and set `flex-grow: 0;`.

However, flexbox is probably not the right solution to your problem in the first place, since you can only align items in one direction.

If you need your columns to be aligned, try [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), which is similar to flexbox but allows you to use both rows AND columns to align your items.

(I know some people have an opposition to W3schools, but [their CSS Grid tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) is helpful for getting started)